# Cannot find modules after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda but still unable to use packages such as pandas and requests when running code on python.

When I input python on Terminal, it shows:

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

And I also created a virtual environment and activate before opening the python shell:

```
conda create -n my-env python=3.6 anaconda
```

However, when reopening and running codes on Python, it kept saying "No module named 'pandas' or "No module named 'requests'" Does anyone know what the problem with this code is? Besides, I am not if version of Python has anything to do with this error? Is it because I am using 3.6.2 Python instead of 3.6.1?

Comment: Are you actually _using_ the environment, with `source activate my-env` or what have you?

Comment: Yes. I entered "source activate my-env" afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Probably Anaconda became the default Python installation on your system. Specially when you are using a new environment, you have to install the modules you want in this new environment.

Try `conda install pandas` and, after that, `import pandas`

Comment: Thanks @Arthur. I just tried installing and importing pandas, but it is still not working. Now I am thinking about this problem might be related to the python shell. When I open the shell, it shows "Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin", which is apparently not a version with Anaconda installed shown on the terminal. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?